# VS2013 Update2 RC Support for SCSS

Tags: visual-studio, sass, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

VS2013 Update 2 claims SCSS support, and indeed I get intellisense which is great. However, scss files are not built into either .css or .min.css files. Is there a step I'm missing or something else I need to install?

The project was originally a VS2011 project where I was using VisualWorkbench for SCSS. This is a new VS2013 install and the project has been upgraded, however, the same thing (no output) seems to happen in a file-new-project scenario.

EDIT

I see now that I need to add the webessentials extension to get compilation. However, this now  throws an exception on compilation

```
17/04/2014 10:43:35: SCSS: Compiling beko_v6.scss
17/04/2014 10:43:36: SCSS: beko_v6.scss compiled.
17/04/2014 10:43:42: An exception was thrown when compiling C:\Data\LocalProjects\Beko2011Azure\Beko2011Azure\Website\Content\beko_v6.scss: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.CorrectionsForScss(String cssFileContents)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.CollectRules(String targetFileName)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.PopulateMap(String targetFileName, String mapFileName)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.Initialize(String targetFileName, String mapFileName, IContentType contentType)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssCompilerResult..ctor(String sourceFileName, String targetFileName, String mapFileName, Boolean isSuccess, String result, IEnumerable`1 errors)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CompilerResultFactory.GenerateResult(String sourceFileName, String targetFileName, String mapFileName, Boolean isSuccess, String result, IEnumerable`1 errors)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.NodeExecutorBase.ProcessResult(Process process, String errorText, String sourceFileName, String targetFileName, String mapFileName)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.NodeExecutorBase.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Compilers.NodeCompilerRunner.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Compilers.CompilerRunnerBase.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Compilers.EditorCompilerInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
17/04/2014 10:43:42: An exception was thrown when compiling C:\Data\LocalProjects\Beko2011Azure\Beko2011Azure\Website\Content\beko_v6.scss: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.CorrectionsForScss(String cssFileContents)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.CollectRules(String targetFileName)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.PopulateMap(String targetFileName, String mapFileName)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssSourceMap.Initialize(String targetFileName, String mapFileName, IContentType contentType)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CssCompilerResult..ctor(String sourceFileName, String targetFileName, String mapFileName, Boolean isSuccess, String result, IEnumerable`1 errors)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CompilerResultFactory.GenerateResult(String sourceFileName, String targetFileName, String mapFileName, Boolean isSuccess, String result, IEnumerable`1 errors)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.NodeExecutorBase.ProcessResult(Process process, String errorText, String sourceFileName, String targetFileName, String mapFileName)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.NodeExecutorBase.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Compilers.NodeCompilerRunner.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Compilers.CompilerRunnerBase.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Compilers.EditorCompilerInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Its fixed by [nightly build](http://vswebessentials.com/download#nightly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vulcanRaven (and Mads via twitter) are right. The nightly build avoids this. To install

http://vswebessentials.com/download#nightly

As well as those instructions you also have to go back into "Extensions and Updates" then online then install the WebEssentials from the newly created WebEssentials Nightly feed.